# firefox print.print_unwriteable_margin_bottom not applying for printer settings

Tags: firefox

[image: Firefox config picture]

First question so I hope I'm doing this right. I have written an asp.net app and it's all complete but one thing. I need page numbers in print. I have found that doing this in code without a reporting tool is nearly impossible so I have opted to force firefox and utilize the about:config features so I can control the header and footer upon print to remove everything but the page numbers. I have exactly what I want now, however, Firefox by default places the footer on top of the edge of the paper and I want to pad this a bit to ensure the printer doesn't cut the page numbers off.

Now my question finally... there are global settings that DO work properly (the header and footer options in my attached picture) where when I invoke the printer, the specific printer settings in about:config take the values I'm placing in the global default fields. There, however, is one setting that does NOT work properly where I'm setting the value as 20, but the specific printer setting just uses the default of 0. If I manually set the specific printer to 20 this does work.

I want to be able to use the global setting because I don't want to be tied to a specific printer so setting the specific printer won't work for my needs.

I have tried just about everything I can think of. I have reset all of the fields countless times, uninstalled firefox, used different PCs, reset firefox completely, tried different margins settings. The issue DOES seem to revolve around the fact that the settings that do work are strings and the settings that do not work are INTs or Booleans as I've tried random other strings that succeed and other INT/Booleans that fail too. FireFox 56.0.2 I'm out of ideas...